# how to display specific Category if post have more one Category?

Tags: categories

how to display specific Category if post have more one Category?

in single.php, i want to get specific Category for post

i need a code that cheks all post Category and display just the one in specific  main Category.

like that

```
$category = get_the_category();

if category( in_parent('11') ){
$parent = $category[1]->category_parent;
}
```

for my site
[maktaba](https://maktaba.live)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confusingly, `get_the_category()` returns an array of categories, so you're going to need to loop through them.

It sounds like you want whichever category is assigned to the current post, and is also a sub-category of category id 11. If that's the case, use

```
<?php
// Get all the categories assigned to this post
$categories = get_the_category();
// Loop through the array that was returned
foreach($categories as $category) {
    // If this category is a sub-category of category 11
    if($category->parent == 11) {
        // Set the $parent to it
        $parent = $category;
        // And exit the foreach loop
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: yes its perfect , thanks alot